# if( condition && condition ) doesn't work,

Tags: javascript

I guess I have some syntax error, I want to check if email have both @ and . in email,
but I'm getting success message only if @ is present.

JavaScript

```
if ( (email.indexOf("@") != -1) && (email.indexOf("." != -1))) { //check if email contains @ and . character
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not jQuery. Just Javascript... You're missing a closing paren.

```
email.indexOf("." != -1)

email.indexOf(".") != -1)
```

Comment: I love how there's no distinction between JS and jQuery nowadays. :)